# Can an Activeadmin Index View be pre-filtered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In my database, I have a number of "projects" and each project has many "devices" associated to it. The admin_users are associated to one or more projects. I have registered a resource that shows the list of devices in the database. This list can be filtered by project.

What I would like to do is to make sure that when a user logs in and goes to the Devices index view, he/she can only view the devices that belongs to his projects. Is this done by pre-filtering the index view? If so, how can I do that? Is there a better way of approaching the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think filters are apropiated for doing this. I would do this in setting the correct @devices instance var in the controller

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @devices = current_admin_user.devices
  end
end
```

and if your admin_user does not know about the devices you can do something like this

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :devices, :through => :projects
end
```

does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn´t work. First, the code inside `def index` did not seem to be executed. Second (and perhaps as a result) in devices.rb inside `index do`, all the calls to display column info such as `column("Account") do |device| ...` are executed for the un-filtered list of devices (i.e. for all of them). I tried adding to deviced.rb `scope_to :current_admin_user, :association_method => :projects` but then it complains about "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: devices.id"